# Difference between 2 datetimes in UTC in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am returning a set of values in a bigquery select statement like this

[image]

I need to add a compute field **Utlization** for each row like this formulae `(end_time - start_time)*cores Utilization`

This time format is in UTC so I am not sure how to do this , I want to do this in the select statement itself. I am new to BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [TIMESTAMP_DIFF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff) function in standard SQL.

In your particular case the query would be something like

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_time , start_time , second)*cores  as Utilization 
FROM <yourtable>
```

Take into consideration that you can change the time unit of the result and you should change it to fit your needs. I inserted second but you can use microsecond, millisecond, second, minute, hour or day.